# Rails/ Mongo db query by object id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query, ruby-on-rails-5

i have a problem with query in ROR

i have a two models, MoStore and MoOrder

```
MoStore: 
class MoStore
include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: 'stores'
  has_many :mo_orders
  
  field :id, type: String
  field :unique_id, type: Integer
  field :email, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  field :phone, type: String
  field :city_id, type: String
  field :country_id, type: String
  field :openpay_id, type: String
  field :address, type: String
  field :country_phone_code, type: String
  field :image_url, type: String
  field :is_approved, type: Boolean
end
```

And

```
 class MoOrder
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: 'orders'
  belongs_to :mo_store
  field :id, type: String
  field :unique_id, type: Integer
  field :store_id, type: String
  field :current_location, type: String
  field :completed_at, type: String
  field :created_at, type: DateTime
  field :order_payment_id, type: String
  field :order_status, type: Integer

end
```

my query in ror is:

```
store = MoStore.find("5ee7b8781514e63a926d8df1")
sales = MoOrder.where(store_id: store.id)
```

when i puts sales.count the result is 0, but in my database have 42 records with field value store_id is "5ee7b8781514e63a926d8df1"

the problem only happens with the fields that are objectid in the database, since with the other fields of other types the where filter works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because rails/ruby thinks your id field is a string type, but it's really a `BSON::ObjectId` type.

Change the id type on your models like so:

```rb
class MoStore
include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: 'stores'
  has_many :mo_orders
  
  field :id, type: BSON::ObjectId
  field :unique_id, type: Integer
  field :email, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  field :phone, type: String
  field :city_id, type: String
  field :country_id, type: String
  field :openpay_id, type: String
  field :address, type: String
  field :country_phone_code, type: String
  field :image_url, type: String
  field :is_approved, type: Boolean
end
```

```rb
class MoOrder
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: 'orders'
  belongs_to :mo_store
  field :id, type: BSON::ObjectId
  field :unique_id, type: Integer
  field :store_id, type: String
  field :current_location, type: String
  field :completed_at, type: String
  field :created_at, type: DateTime
  field :order_payment_id, type: String
  field :order_status, type: Integer

end
```

And change your query to:

```rb
store = MoStore.find(BSON::ObjectId.from_string("5ee7b8781514e63a926d8df1"))
```

Then this should work.